# Installing rbtree on PyPy

Tags: python, tree, pypy

I'm trying to install [rbtree](https://bitbucket.org/bcsaller/rbtree/) as a PyPy module. I read that some modules are not compatible with PyPy. 
Is there any way to install it properly or any alternative? I'm looking for a tree dictionary that also can be browsed like tree[0:100] (subscriptable) and that also supports item assignment.
I tried to install it with the following command but I got lots of errors:

```
pypy setup.py install
```

Comment: can you share the output with errors you got during installation?

Comment: Here it is :) http://pastebin.com/B5as6u8G

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with slightly different API, the easiest way is to look for other modules that do the same in pure Python code.  There is for example this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/binary_tree_dict_mod.  A pure Python version will be much faster than a CPython-C-API-compatible version in PyPy.